# d3 trying to open html in div or iframe on click

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 bar chart and I would like to have it so when a bar is clicked on the chart, HTML is loaded in another section of the page. As I've been trying to research how to do this, I am becoming more and more confused. Should I use a `<div>` or an `<iframe>`? I have this which works as far as a clicking event goes:

```
.on("click", function() { alert("Hello world"); })
```

But I don't think I can use it since I want different bars to open different content. So I also need to figure out how to tie which bar is clicked to which file is opened. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an onclick event which passes clicked bar reference to the function which loads html.

```
.on('click', function(d) {loadHtml(d)});
```

Then create a loadHtml function

```
function loadHtml(clickedBar)
{
  if (clickedBar[0] = "foo")
  {
      $('#DivForLoadingHtml').load("http://mydomain.xyz/foo.htm");
  }   
  if (clickedBar[0] = "bar")
  {
      $('#DivForLoadingHtml').load("http://mydomain.xyz/bar.htm");
  } 

}
```

Comment: I suggest you use a regular function instead of an arrow function: in D3, we use `this` a lot. In a regular function, `this` will be the clicked rectangle, but not in an arrow function.

Comment: I looked at this example for my answer.  Arrow function seemed to return the clicked bar.  https://jsfiddle.net/robturtle/60we6hkn/

Comment: No, it doesn't: it simply removes the datum and redraw the chart. The bar disappears because of the `selection.exit()`.

Comment: Yes true thanks for pointing out the distinction.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Returning to my original question and not knowing what I am doing...what would a function that loads html look like? If I want to load the content into part of the same web page, should it be a div or iframe?

Comment: I have updated answer with an example of the LoadHtml function using a div.  Either div or iframe will work however with a div it is important that the html files you are loading are hosted on the same domain or you might run into XSS type issues.  If this is not the case you may be better with an iframe.

Comment: Thank you very much! That clears it up immensely and solves the problem. I appreciate it!