# Open html on click using data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got a great answer on my related question here:
[d3 trying to open html in div or iframe on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543331/d3-trying-to-open-html-in-div-or-iframe-on-click) which is shown below

```
.on('click', function(d) {
    loadHtml(d)
});


function loadHtml(clickedBar) {
    if (clickedBar[0] = "foo") {
        $('#DivForLoadingHtml').load("http://mydomain.xyz/foo.htm");
    }
    if (clickedBar[0] = "bar") {
        $('#DivForLoadingHtml').load("http://mydomain.xyz/bar.htm");
    }
}
```

I have a datafile that looks like this:

```
gamedate    value  gamefile
6/27/2001   27     062701.htm
9/12/2001   49     091201.htm
9/23/2001   64     092301.htm
```

I'm trying to figure out how to change the answer from the previous question so that when someone clicks on a bar in the graph, it opens the file specified in the `gamefile` column in a designated `<div>`. I assume I need to define `gamefile` somewhere but I don't comprehend the whole loadHtml well enough to know how to set it up to pull from that variable. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **don't** mix D3 and jQuery, as in the linked answer. That not only is unnecessary, but can make things (silently) fail.

The easiest way to open a new window is using [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). You just need to pass the datum (the first argument) to the listener and using the correct property.

So, in your case:

```
selection.on("click", function(d){
    window.open(d.gamefile)
})
```

Here is a basic demo, click on the bars: https://jsfiddle.net/kcs5cwz2/

**PS**: I normally write my answers using the stack snippet. It's better than external links, like JSFiddle, Plunker, CodePen, Bl.ocks etc... However, the [stack snippet blocks window.open()](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337916/5768908).

Comment: So in my original question, and perhaps the reason why I had jQuery with the d3, I needed the html files to be opened in a div on the existing page. I don't think I can do that with window.open. If I'm not mistaken that will only open a new tab or window, not load into a section of the existing page.

Comment: You're asking a different thing here. My answer deals with what you asked in your question.

Comment: "I'm trying to figure out how to change the answer from the previous question". I will edit my question so that what I need is clearer.